# Нужно ли использовать Service слой для классов, не работающих с БД?

Tags: java, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, service

В целом понимаю зачем нужно создавать Service при работе с Repositoty и DAO.

Но возник вопрос, а нужно ли использовать Service для классов, которые содержат важную бизнес-логику, но отдают инфу не путем обращения к БД, а, например, что-то просчитывают или парсят какие-то документы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service - это промежуточный слой вэб приложения, между Controller и Repository не больше, не меньше, но его чаще всего используют для внедрения в его бизнес-логики. Бизнес-логику желательно держать отдельно от сервиса и  и внедрять ее по мере необходимости. По сути Service интегрирует все необходимые компоненты, которые потом передаются в Controller, но не напрямую, а через Service.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но, думаю, у меня не вышло правильно сформулировать вопрос. Попробую на примере. Допустим у нас есть:
1.Класс NumberGenerator с набором методов, возвращающих случайные числа; 
2.Cущность Number, у которой есть id, дата генерации, и число, выданное генератором; 
3.NumberRepository для просмотра и добавления сгенерированных Number; 
Далее мы создаем NumberService и инжектим туда NumberReposotory.
Вопрос такой: что делать с NumberGenerator? Внедрить в NumberService? Создать отдельный NumberGeneratorService? Вызывать его напрямую в контроллере? Буду благодарен за пояснения!

Comment: Правильно, внедрить NumberGenerator в NumberService, если это можно. В контроллере он не нужен? Все делать через сервис, так будет более логично.